# What type of problems can mapreduce solve?

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce

Is there a theoretical analysis available which describes what kind of problems mapreduce can solve?

Answer (score 9):

In [Map-Reduce for Machine Learning on Multicore](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/people/ang/papers/nips06-mapreducemulticore.pdf) Chu *et al* describe "algorithms that fit the Statistical Query model can be written in a certain “summation form,” which allows them to be easily parallelized on multicore computers." They specifically implement 10 algorithms including e.g. weighted linear regression, k-Means, Naive Bayes, and SVM, using a map-reduce framework.

The [Apache Mahout](http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/) project has released a recent Hadoop (Java) implementation of some methods based on the ideas from this paper.

Answer (score 5):

For problems requiring processing and generating large data sets. Say running an interest generation query over all accounts a bank hold. Say processing audit data for all transactions that happened in the past year in a bank. The best use case is from Google - generating search index for google search engine.

Answer (score 5):

Many problems that are "Embarrassingly Parallel" (great phrase!) can use MapReduce. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel

From this article....
http://www.businessweek.com/magazine/content/07_52/b4064048925836.htm
...

Doug Cutting, founder of Hadoop (an open source implementation of MapReduce) says...
“Facebook uses Hadoop to analyze user behavior and the effectiveness of ads on the site"

and...  “the tech team at The New York Times rented computing power on Amazon’s cloud and used Hadoop to convert 11 million archived articles, dating back to 1851, to digital and searchable documents. They turned around in a single day a job that otherwise would have taken months.”

Answer (score 3):

Anything that involves doing operations on a large set of data, where the problem can be broken down into smaller independent sub-problems who's results can then be aggregated to produce the answer to the larger problem.

A trivial example would be calculating the sum of a huge set of numbers.  You split the set into smaller sets, calculate the sums of those smaller sets in parallel (which can involve splitting those into yet even smaller sets), then sum those results to reach the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies is really in the name of the algorithm.  MapReduce is not a general purpose parallel programming work or batch execution framework as some of the answers suggest.  Map Reduce is really useful when **large** data sets that need to be processed (Mapping phase) and derive certain attributes from there, and then need to be summarized on on those derived attributes (Reduction Phase).

Answer (score 2):

You can also watch the [videos @ Google](http://code.google.com/intl/en/edu/submissions/mapreduce-minilecture/listing.html), I'm watching them myself and I find them very educational.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a hello world introduction to MapReduce

http://blog.diskodev.com/parallel-processing-using-the-map-reduce-prog

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked before its time. Since 2009 there has actually been a theoretical analysis of MapReduce computations. This 2010 paper of [Howard Karloff et al.](http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/soda10-mrc.pdf) formalizes MapReduce as a complexity class in the same way that theoreticians study P and NP. They prove some relationships between MapReduce and a class called NC (which can be thought of either as shared-memory parallel machines or a certain class of restricted circuits). But the main piece of work are their formal definitions.